# How to make an image\video\flash to show on hyperlink mouseover?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, hyperlink, onmouseover

I have the idea of images displaying in a frame (XAML) on mouseover. 
However I want different images to display for each hyperlink. I assume it is only possible in C# and not XAML itself.

Simply put - I have 1 (single) frame in XAML. I want it's source to be changed on mouseover. For instance when mouse is over Hyperlink "Link1" - I want the frame to navigate to page named m1x; when mouse is over Hyperlink "Link2" - navigate to m2x, etc.

Is that possible?

Example:

*XAML:*

## Frame

```
    <DockPanel>
        <Frame x:Name="movFrame" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" RenderTransformOrigin="0.494,1.151" Margin="0,170,0,-104" Width="267" />

    </DockPanel>
```

## Hyperlink

```
    <Hyperlink x:Name="Link1" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigateI" NavigateUri="P2.xaml"><Run Text="1. Get Properties of Chemical Element (Si)"/></Hyperlink>
```

*C#*

## Hyperlink_RequestNavigateI

```
public void Hyperlink_RequestNavigateI(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
{
    Uri m1x = new Uri("m1.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
    if (Link1.IsMouseOver)
    {
        movFrame.Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate
        {
            movFrame.Source = m1x;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: if you can display 1 frame in XAMl then ofcourse you can do the same with multiple, but I personally prefer c#

Comment: Maybe look at JQuery solutions such as http://lukasz-design.pl/codecanyon/mTip/index.html and http://qtip2.com/demos

Comment: I know how to do it with javascript or jquery, but it's too much code to integrate in a C# WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure to use with XAML and C#, then you can opt for **Popup**; I have mentioned 'ToggleButton'. But it can be replaced with Hyperlink based on your wish;

```
<ToggleButton>
    <ToggleButton.Template>
    <Popup Placement="Bottom" HorizontalOffset="250" VerticalOffset="10" 
    PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=Button1}"
    IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked}" StaysOpen="False">
         <local:PopupView/>
    </Popup>
    </ToggleButton.Template>
</ToggleButton>
```

*StaysOpen="False"* => initially it will be in closed state.

Comment: @user3410566, If you feel the solution is helpful, mark it as Answer which will be helpful for others those who refer.